# ubuntu 12.04.3 with gnome: some shortcuts e.g. [alt]+[f2] do not work

Tags: shortcut-keys

the above mentioned shortcut does not work, as well as <kbd>strg</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for terminal. But for example <kbd>strg</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> for locking the session runs fine.

Some do, some not, and I don't know where to look for this in the system settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution**

You can give a try to this option. You'll get a lot of configuration to set your own `Shortcut Key`.

Follow these steps:

- Open `Keyboard` from `System Settings` (or Search in *dash*)
- Chose <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> tab
- Go to `Custom Shortcuts` to set a new key to run any application. For example you can set `gnome-terminal` to execute in press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which I think is missing for you. You can set any thing you want.
- I am attaching a screenshot which shows the shortcuts for `Navigation`.

[image]

I hope you would get your missing keys.. Reply if you need further assistance..

Answer (score 0):

It was my own mistake. There's a special "function" key on my keyboard, which was turned on (don't know why). <kbd>F2</kbd> for example is set with "undo". So this could not work, like an activated <kbd>shift</kbd> key while entering passwords.

Now everything is fine, and next time I hope I remember this key.